# How to get Serial Communications from wxPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, wxpython, pyserial

I have a problem developing a program that uses wxPython's GUI to communicate serially.

When I press the 'OPEN' button, the SerialPort opens with the serial port selected in ComboBox and BaudRate entered in TextCtrl, and I want to display the data entered into that port on the terminal screen.

In this code, we succeeded in opening and closing the Serial Port through the 'OPEN' and 'Close' buttons, but we would like to know how to display the data coming through the Serial Port on the terminal screen in real time.

```
import wx
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports as SerialPort  

class MyApp(wx.Frame):
    portList = []
    portSelect = ''
    ser = serial.Serial()

    def __init__(self):
        self.SearchSerialPort()
        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, title = "SerialCSV", size = (500, 150), style =wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        
        # PORT list text
        self.select = wx.StaticText(panel, label = "PORT Select      : ")
        self.select.SetPosition((10, 10))

        # BaudRate text
        self.select = wx.StaticText(panel, label = "PORT BaudRate : ")
        self.select.SetPosition((10, 40))

        # PORT list comboBox
        self.Combo = wx.ComboBox(panel, -1, "Select", (106, 7), (110,22), self.portList)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.PortSelect)

        # BaudRate inputBox
        self.BR = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, size = (110, 22), pos=(106,37))
        
        # Connect Button
        self.ConnectButton = wx.Button(panel, label="OPEN", size = (80, 52), pos=(230, 7))
        self.ConnectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.SerialConnect)
        
        # DisConnect Button
        self.DisConnectButton = wx.Button(panel, label="Close", size = (80, 52), pos=(310, 7))
        self.DisConnectButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SerialDisConnect)


    def SearchSerialPort(self) : 
        ports = SerialPort.comports()
        
        for p in ports :
            self.portList.append(p.device)


    def PortSelect(self, event) :
        self.portSelect = self.portList[event.GetSelection()]

    
    def SerialConnect(self, event) : 
        if self.ser.is_open == False :
            ReadBaudrate = self.BR.GetValue()
            print(ReadBaudrate)
            
            if ReadBaudrate == '' :
                print("!! Input BaudRate !!")
            
            else :
                self.ser = serial.Serial(port = self.portSelect, baudrate = ReadBaudrate)
                print(self.portSelect + " PORT Open")
            
        else : 
            print("already open... [ " + self.portSelect + " ]" )
        

    def SerialRead(self) : 
        if self.ser.is_open == True :
            if self.ser.readable():
                res = self.ser.readline()
                print(res.decode()[:len(res)-1])
            

    def SerialDisConnect(self, event) : 
        self.ser.close()
        print("PORT Close")

        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You need to use some sort of timer to regularly call the `SerialRead()` method. What timers does the `wxPython` framework offer?

Comment: wxPython provides a timer called wxTimer. 
It was my first project to use GUI, so I didn't think of "Timer," and I thought about how to use "while," "for," or "thread."

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Yes, with all GUI frameworks (and some other frameworks) that are event driven its not a good idea to have long running loops. Its much better to use an event provided by the framework to repeatedly call some of your own code. (And that code should do something and return as quickly as possible)

Comment: There seems to be a sample program called [wxTerminal.py](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/examples/wxTerminal.py) in PySerial. Have you tried or investigated it?